# Tighten steel wire across several wood posts

Tags: fence, wire

I have several 4" x4" wood posts, with one single piece of steel wire going through each post.

Something like this:
[image]

Is there anything I can use to tighten and secure the wire in each post?

The first and last post will have a regular hook for the wire.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a "barrel strainer" to tighten each horizontal run of wire.

[image: barrel strainer]

Otherwise you can buy tensioners and "through-collar" kits specifically for cable fencing systems.

[image: through-collar kit]

Comment: Also called "turn -buckles".

Comment: I understand I can use the turnbuckle in the first and last post, but how would I use it in the middle posts? Remember that it's only one piece of wire rope going though all the posts.

Comment: You wouldn't use turnbuckles at intermediate posts. Usually the wires are not supporting the posts. If you want to secure wire to posts use stop collars with set screws as pictured. @rbhat

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are looking for is a wire stretcher.

https://www.agrisupply.com/wire-stretchers/c/2200013/

Comment: Wire stretchers are for stretching the wire, the OP is looking for the way to secure the wire to the post.   Why, is a mystery. *This  is not an answer to the question*. Turnbuckles on the end  post will stretch the wire, Securing at each post is usually not done or needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have tightened or stretched many types of fencing over the years, never bought a stretcher...

We would get two 2*4 of a suitable length (just longer than the fence height), then drill and fit 3 or 5 bolts that would clamp them together. A couple of holes for the rope or chain to go through and we were ready.

Clamp the fence between the 2*4 and tighten the bolts. Then use a rope or chain for a handwinch or spanish windlass to pull on.

If the first and last posts are not strong enough they can be pulled out of the ground.. We had our corner posts set in 5 foot and bracing as necessary.

The wire is secured at the start and the end but only loosely fixed in the middle posts so it cannot get pushed down by the cattle - but allows movement horizontally. We used wire staples for the middle fixings.